# How to hide menu item if it doesn't contain any subitems?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have the following menu item in XAML:

```xml
<MenuItem Visibility="{Binding SetToSpecificMacroCommand, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Header="{x:Static res:Strings.SetToSpecificMacro}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableMacros}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Key}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Key}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Icons/PlaceMacro16.png" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

The `AvailableMacros` property (bound to `MenuItem`'s `ItemsSource`) is an `IEnumerable<MacroKeyViewModel>`, and, what is most important, it **has** to stay `IEnumerable`, because it **must** be re-evaluated every time menu opens.

The menu item itself serves no purpose except for showing subitems, therefore I'd like to hide it if only there are no subitems available.

I could bind `Visibility` of the `MenuItem` to `AvailableMacros` with a converter (which would check if there are any available), but in effect the property would get evaluated twice, what would slow down the UI (especially that I have a couple of menu items of this kind).

How can I hide menu item if there were no sub-items without need for evaluating `AvailableMacros` twice?

Comment: You don't need a converter you can check for `AvailableMacros.Count` being `0` in a DataTrigger and set Visibility to Collapsed if 0. Should be an observable collection, oc

Comment: @lidqy, The `IEnumerable<MacroKeyViewModel>` type does not have a Count property.

Comment: @EldHasp WPF looks at the actual Runtime type not on the formal declaration. And there is virtually nothing that is just an IEnumerable<T>. Anything is a class and most IEnumerable<T> are also ICollection<T> (or ICollection without T) having a Count property.

Comment: @Spook "_it has to stay IEnumerable, because it must be re-evaluated every time menu opens._" If you had an ObservableCollection for AvailableMacros you'd notice all changes you need to notice in time. WPF ItemsControls have are recommended to bind to collections that implement the non-generic "IList". If the collection's count changes at runtime it's best to bind to sth that implements _INotifyCollectionChanged_. Of course it's up to you how you shape your data.

Comment: @lidqy, `IEnumerable<T>` may be as well a method using `yield return` and `yield break` statements - it doesn't have Count property. I also can not use ObservableCollection, because every time menu is opened, this entries are *generated*. They are retrieved by traversing hierarchical structure and maintaining complete list at any point would cost a lot of computing time and memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need a full pass to determine visibility. It is enough to check with the Any() method the presence of at least one element.
2. You can also use checking not the collection itself in the ViewModel's property, but its presentation (CollectionView), which provides the Items property:

```xml
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static res:Strings.SetToSpecificMacro}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableMacros}">
            <MenuItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Key}" />
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Key}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Icons/PlaceMacro16.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
```

**P.S.** Compared to the costs inherent in WPF, I think even going through the collection ten times will not introduce any noticeable additional costs.